# Could not instantiate the box MyServer with provider Virtualbox, definition 'MyServer' does not exist

Tags: vagrant, veewee

I am new to vagrant and am building my first basebox. After installation and configuration of the downloaded template (Oracle Linux) I attempted to do a "vagrant basebox export" but got the following error:

Could not instantiate the box MyServer with provider Virtualbox, definition 'MyServer' does not exist. Are you sure you are in the top directory?

I am executing from the directory where MyServer.vbox resides (which I assume is correct).

I am running Oracle Virtual Box 3.x, ruby 1.9.3, vagrant (gem) 1.07 and veewee (gem) 0.3.12.

I am able to execute some basebox commands, i.e., vagrant basebox templates.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: Nothing. It's a Vagrant/Veewee configuration issue, hence the tags.

Comment: Should be on http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You  have to found the Vagrant up and running books. It is good for starting.!!

Answer (score 0):

only need to download the lasted version of baseboxes from [here](http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html).
If you are new working with Vagrant (like me) you have to read these [source](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html).

I hope that help you